# Why is the תפילת גשם, The prayer for rain, said on Shmini Atzeres, rather than on Hashanahah Rabbah?

Tags: tefilla, minhag, sukkot

Mishnah /Rosh Hashanah 1:2 - - משנה ראש השנה פרק א משנה א

> בְּאַרְבָּעָה פְרָקִים הָעוֹלָם נִדּוֹן, בְּפֶסַח עַל הַתְּבוּאָה,
>   בַּעֲצֶרֶת עַל פֵּרוֹת הָאִילָן, בְּרֹאשׁ הַשָּׁנָה כָּל בָּאֵי
>   הָעוֹלָם עוֹבְרִין לְפָנָיו כִּבְנֵי מָרוֹן... **וּבֶחָג נִדּוֹנִין
>   עַל הַמָּיִם**:
>
> At four times the world is judged: On Pesach, for the crops. On
>   Shavuot, for the fruits of the tree. On Rosh Hashnah, all the world
>   passes before Him like sheep, ... **And on Sukkot, they are judged for
>   the water.**

Gemarah Rosh Hashanah 16a

> ומפני מה אמרה תורה נסכו מים בחג אמר הקדוש ברוך הוא **נסכו לפני מים בחג
>   כדי שיתברכו לכם גשמי שנה**  - And for what reason did the Torah say:
>   Pour water onto the altar in the Temple on the festival of Sukkot? The
>   Holy One, Blessed be He, said: **Pour water before Me on the festival of
>   Sukkot so that the rains of the year will be blessed for you.**

Mishnah Sukkah 4:1

> לוּלָב וַעֲרָבָה, שִׁשָּׁה וְשִׁבְעָה. הַהַלֵּל וְהַשִּׂמְחָה, שְׁמֹנָה. סֻכָּה **וְנִסּוּךְ הַמַּיִם, שִׁבְעָה**. וְהֶחָלִיל,
>   חֲמִשָּׁה וְשִׁשָּׁה: The [shaking of the] lulav and the [ritual of
>   the] willow [branches were each done, at times] on six [days of the
>   festival], and [at times] on seven. The [recitation of the] Hallel,
>   and the simchah [the obligation to bring Shelamim sacrifices to the
>   Temple as part of the rejoicing on the three pilgrimage festivals]
>   were each done on eight [days]. The [dwelling in the] sukkah, **and
>   the water libations [were each done] on seven [days].** And the flute
>   [was played, at times] on five, and [at times] on six.**

Tur OC 664:1 -  טור אורח חיים סימן תרסד סעיף א

> ביום חמישי של חול המועד שהוא הושענא רבה נוהגין שמרבין מזמורים כמו בי"ט
>   ואומר קדושה רבה במוסף ומרבים קצת בנרות כמו ביום כיפור **לפי שבחג
>   נדונין על המים והכל הולך אחר החתום וכל חיי אדם תלויין במים**
>
> On the fifth day of Chol Hamoed, which is Hoshanah Rabbah it is
>   customary to add extra songs [in the prayers] like on Yom-tov, And a longer *kedusha* is said, and some additional candles are lit like on Yom kippur, **Because on Sukkot we are Judged for water, and all is dependent on the sealing [of the decree], and all human life depends on water.**

ומרבים קצת בנרות כמו ביום הכפורים: הגה והמדקדקים נוהגים לטבול עצמן קודם עלות השחר כמו בערב יום כיפור [מנהגים] ויש נוהגים ללבוש הקיטל כמו ביום כפור **לפי שבחג נידונים על המים** ... **ומרבים תחנונים על המים**:

And some additional candles are lit like on Yom kippur,  and those who are meticulous tend to immerse themselves before dawn, as on Erev Yom kippur, and some have the custom to wear a kittel to practice *kittel* like on yom Kippur, **because on Sukkot we are judged for water... and many pleas are said for water.**

Also Shulchan Aruch OC 664:1 -  שולחן ערוך אורח חיים סימן תרסד סעיף א

> ביום שביעי שהוא הושענא רבה נוהגים להרבות במזמורים כמו ביום טוב: ... On
>   the seventh day [of Sukkot] which is *Hoshanah Rabbah* it is customary
>   to add extra songs [in the prayers] like on Yom-tov.
>
> See Mishnah Berurah there: כמו ביו"ט - לפי שבחג נידונין על המים והוא
>   גמר החתימה - Like on Yom Tov - **Because on Sukkot we are judged for
>   water, and this [day] is the final signing of the decree.**
>
> ומרבים קצת בנרות כמו ביום הכפורים: הגה והמדקדקים נוהגים לטבול עצמן
>   קודם עלות השחר כמו בערב יום כיפור [מנהגים] ויש נוהגים ללבוש הקיטל כמו
>   ביום כפור **לפי שבחג נידונים על המים** ... **ומרבים תחנונים על המים**:
>
> And some additional candles are lit like on Yom kippur,  and those who
>   are meticulous tend to immerse themselves before dawn, as on Erev Yom
>   kippur, and some have the custom to wear a kittel to practice *kittel*
>   like on yom Kippur, **because on Sukkot we are judged for water... and
>   many pleas are said for water.**

From all this we see that the judgement of water / rain  for the year takes place during the **seven days of Sukkot**, and the final decree is given **on the seventh day which is *Hoshanah Rabbah*.**

Question:

If so, why is the תפילת גשם, The prayer for rain, said on *Shmini Atzeres*, The eighth day, which is no longer Sukkot, and is after the closing of the final decree for water, rather than on Hashanahah Rabbah?

Comment: Have you see Mishna Taanit 1:1?

Comment: There are many many תפילות for גשם recited on Hoshana Rabba too (as your sources say), and rain isn't formally requested in the Amida until weeks later anyway. Why you are focusing on one particular petition for rain on Shmini Atzeret in that whole context is greatly unclear. Are you stuck on its modern name? That's hardly such a significant feature. The name probably isn't even that old.

Comment: (Incidentally does תפלת גשם literally mean prayer for rain or prayer about rain? I'd guess the latter, no?)

Comment: @DoubleAA Even if it means "about" it is still a prayer FOR rain.

Comment: Not sure but even if so that'd probably only be because it's holding like an opinion we don't rule like. The Israeli Minhag in the time of the Kalir was to request rain starting on [motzaei] shmini atzeret, not two weeks later like is commonly practiced nowadays. אמונים גנון בם שואלי מטר wasn't just poetic. (Probably nowadays they should change it to מזכירי מטר)

Comment: The easiest way to think about this is to remember whose judgment is sealed on Hoshanah Rabbah (see the Tur) and who Shemini Atzeret is intended for (the 70 Parim which corresponds to the 70 nations were completed the day before). The judgement on Hoshanah Rabbah is on the 70 nations. Shemini Atzeret is only directed to the Jewish people.

Comment: @YaacovDeane The judgement on Hoshanah Rabbah is on the 70 nations. Shemini Atzeret is only directed to the Jewish people. So the "final decree" mentioned in the tur is referring to goyim?? and we jews act like yom kippur because its the final judgement day for goyim??

Comment: @RibbisRabbiAndMore Yes, you have the right idea. Like the Tur points out, the 3rd & final stage of the war of Gog miGog begins on Hoshanah Rabbah. And as presented in Navi, it has the potential to go pretty badly for the 70 nations. Think of the practice we learn from the Prophets of striking the 5 aravot on the floor to sweeten the judgement on Hoshanah Rabbah. Like with the rest of Sukkot, we pray on their behalf and for their benefit. Look at the text after the Hosha’anot. It is about the final redemption and the revelation of HaShem’s kingship.

Comment: @YaacovDeane Sorry. That is definitely not the way most of the commentaries that i have seen explain the "yom hadin" of HR, that its all about judgement & praying for the goyim.

Comment: @RibbisRabbiAndMore Perhaps you should consider learning more about how the Lubavitcher Rebbe teaches the subject. It is his teaching and he is generally considered knowledgeable in matters of Torah and halacha.

Comment: @YaacovDeane The Lubavitcher Rebbe  is one among many many others considered knowledgeable in matters of Torah and halacha.

Comment: @RibbisRabbiAndMore True, there are others who are considered knowledgeable, but in your own words, most of those you have seen don’t teach this detail. That suggests that you need to broaden your exposure.  The Rebbe isn’t making chiddushim on this. He is bringing traditional teaching from classic sources. Another big plus is that he provides copious footnotes with detailed citations to everything. Learning the Rebbe’s discourses and talks without the footnotes is leaving more than half of the money on the table. We are all obligated to know the whole Torah, each according to their capacity.

Answer (score 1):

Sefer Hatodaa page 126 says that as we are judged on Succos for water we really should say Tefilas Geshem on the first day of Succos just like we say Tal on the first day of Pesach. However the Gemara Succos 28b explains that rain on Succos is not a good sign since we can not sit in the Sukkah when it rains. Therefore we first pay for Geshem once Succos is over.

Comment: Thank you. Though that makes me wonder why we do say all the other rain prayers on Hoshanah Rabbah.